# Make tests in multi project sbt projects run only if tests pass in dependent projects

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

Assuming a multiproject SBT project with a foo-project and bar-project, such that foo-project depends on bar-project for code etc.

I would like tests in foo-project to run iff the tests in bar-project pass.

How?

Comment: Why would you like to avoid running those? Seems like foo tests have dependency to bar implementation (instead of bar API), otherwise you probably wouldn't mind have them running. Isn't that the problem you want to solve in the first place?

Comment: We are having two problems: the first is its possible for some tests to fail in a multi-project build but the overall build passes, and you don't notice the failure whizz by on the console. The second is that we would like to run unit tests before running time-consuming browser tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may provide explicit dependencies between projects. For example *root -> A -> B*

[Test case on GitHub](https://github.com/ezh/funny-case-for-SF20266383). Project definition:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1")

lazy val a: Project = (project in file("a")) settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
    name := "a",
    test in Test <<= test in Test dependsOn (test in Test in b)
)

lazy val b: Project = (project in file("b")) settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
    name := "b"
)

lazy val root: Project = (project in file(".")) settings(commonSettings: _*) settings(
    name := "root",
    test in Test <<= test in Test dependsOn (test in Test in a)
)
```

Beginning from B and complete them successful:

```
ezh@mobile ZZZZZZ % sbt-0.13                                          
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/ezh/ZZZZZZ/)
> root/test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ezh/ZZZZZZ/b/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] TestSpecB:
[info] This test 
[info] - should fail
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ezh/ZZZZZZ/a/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] TestSpecA:
[info] This test 
[info] - should succeed
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for root/test:test
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 28.11.2013 16:20:12
```

Beginning from B but fail:

```
ezh@mobile ZZZZZZ % sbt-0.13                                          
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/ezh/ZZZZZZ/)
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ezh/ZZZZZZ/b/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] TestSpecB:
[info] This test 
[info] - should fail *** FAILED ***
[info]   2 did not equal 3 (Test.scala:5)
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         TestSpecB
[error] (b/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 28.11.2013 16:20:35
>
```

Answer (score 0):

as already noted this is probably evil, however this should probably work:

```
import sbt._
    import sbt.Keys._
    object Build extends Build {
      lazy val projectA = project
      lazy val myTest = taskKey[Seq[Option[Tests.Output]]]("my test")
      lazy val root: Project = project in file(".") settings (myTest <<= myTestTask) dependsOn projectA

      def myTestTask = Def.task {
        val state: State = Keys.state.value
        val log: Logger = streams.value.log
        val extracted = Project.extract(state)
        import extracted._
        def noTestsMessage(scoped: ScopedKey[_])(implicit display: Show[ScopedKey[_]]): String =
          "No tests to run for " + display(scoped)
        def f(ref: ProjectReference) = for {
          state Pair Value(r) <- Project.runTask(executeTests in(ref, Test), state)
          _ = Tests.showResults(log, r, noTestsMessage(test in ref))
        } yield r
        val depsTests = currentProject.dependencies.map(_.project).map(f)
        val passed = depsTests.forall(_.forall(_.overall == TestResult.Passed))
        if (passed) depsTests :+ f(ThisProject) else depsTests
      }
    }
```

http://scastie.org/3319